# Kendo / IE / Caching

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm working with Kendo UI's drop down list.

In my application, I am updating a drop down list dynamically, based on a set of criteria.

My drop down list is updating correctly across all browsers, except IE.

In IE, my drop down list only updates when my DEV Tools toolbar is open.

When the toolbar is not open, my list will not update.

Has anyone encountered this behavior before? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your title suggests you already thought about a problem related to caching. IE does not have the same caching behavior as other browsers.

Look at the http response headers and check if a cache control header is present.
If you are new to cache control headers i would suggest reading this [Cache Headers - a beginners guide](http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/)

---

Why does it work when the toolbar is open?

Have a look at the top of your toolbar and check if any of those options are activated (if so, deactivate them to get the same behavior as with closed Dev tools).
[DEV Toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfJSP.png)

Comment: Yeah, I just found the problem now, apparently IE 11(possibly others?) has an "Always Refresh from Server" option. This is selected in my dev tools. So yeah, it is most def. a cache issue.

Comment: How does the cache control section in your response header look like, or is there any?

Comment: I had manually set the output cache. My responce headers cache control appears as : 
Cache-Control public, max-age=0, s-maxage=0

Answer (score 0):

adding cache false solve my issue.

```
...
transport: {
    read: {
        url: "yoururl",
        cache: false
    }
},
...
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
$("#yourDropDown").data("kendoDropDownList").dataSource.read();
```

When you have to update your DropDownList

Comment: try to add .ServerFiltering(true); in the dropdownlist.
[Telerik Forum](http://www.telerik.com/forums/prevent-ajax-caching-on-read)

Comment: I have tried this, no success. The answer was just to pass a date as a parameter.